# First password entry almost always fails after waking from sleep

Tags: usb, keyboard, windows-10

Just like the title says, if I've woken my computer from sleep and go to enter my password, it almost always fails the first time, and it looks like only some of the keys I type have been inserted (fewer dots than normal).

I suspect the keyboard isn't being recognized right away, but how can I fix this or make it more responsive?

I'm using a Happy Hacking Keyboard Pro 2 connected via USB directly to the motherboard.

Comment: Might it be that you use the first key to wake up your computer, which *isn't recognized as a keystroke*, and that's why your password is not correct?

Comment: @nKn my mouse and keyboard both don't wake the computer. I push the power button to wake it.